# Pasar El texto del Contenedor <span id> a una Variable PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Tengo un Videojuego programado en HTML y JavaScript del cual deseo pasar los puntos logrados a la Base de Datos MySQL y no encuentro la forma correcta de lograrlo.

Código JavaScript:

```
function updateScore(){
    var score = (snakeLength - startLength) * 10;
    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score;
}

function gameScore() {
    $('#ribbon').addClass('hide');
    var highScore = localStorage.getItem("high-score");
    var score = (snakeLength - startLength) * 10;
    $('.current-score').html(score);
    if (score > highScore) {
        $('#ribbon').removeClass('hide');
        $('.high-score').html(score);
        localStorage.setItem('high-score', score);
    } else {
        $('.high-score').html(highScore);}
        gameMenu();
    }
```

Código HTML (muestra los puntos actuales del videojuego):

```
Puntos: <span id="score">0< /span>
```

Código PHP:

Necesito realizar un update de puntos en mi Base de Datos pero no se como pasar la etiqueta `<span id="score">` a una variable PHP. Por AJAX sería lo ideal pero se me hace mas difícil.

```
// Necesito El Resultado en Point 
mysql_query("UPDATE game SET point=$VARIABLE_PUNTOS ");
```

Comment: Hola Bryan, ¿qué parte exactamente de usar AJAX se te complica? Ya estás usando jQuery, usar AJAX es relativamente [sencillo](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: Si , creo que seria lo mejor pero la base de datos siempre la he manejado desde php , hay alguna manera de hacerlo sin AJAX? Y pues me encanta AJAX pero para los que empezamos en esa Tecnología se los complica un poco

Comment: Estoy Probando y me Realiza el UPDATE Pero POST no logra LLEVAR el Resultado Score Aún.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás tratando de evitar usar AJAX, sin embargo, no es muy difícil hacerlo. Usando jQuery haces el POST con la información del `score`:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "/score.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        "score": $("#score").text()
    }
});
request.done(function(response) {
    console.log("¡Bien!")
});
request.fail(function(response) {
    console.log("¡Error!")
});
```

En PHP:

```
...
$score = $_POST['score'];
mysql_query("UPDATE game SET point=$score ");
...
```

Es mejor prevenir, te iría mejor usando [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) para evitar [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL):

```
...
$score = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['score']);
mysql_query("UPDATE game SET point=$score ");
...
```

---

Ya que estás usando HTML y JavaScript en tu juego, te recomendaría usar una Base de Datos cloud tipo [Parse](http://www.parse.com/). Te puedes ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza.

### Actualización

Recuerda que si el atributo es un `class`:

```
<span class="current-score">0</span>
```

Debes usar `.` en vez de `#`, `#` es para cuando usas `id`:

```
var score = $(".current-score").text();
```

Si necesitas pasarlo a entero y sumarlo puedes usar `parseInt`:

```
var score = parseInt($(".current-score").text()) + 50;
```

Comment: Exelente! Probare su Código, le Comunicare el Resultado

Comment: Mejor que usar `mysql_real_escape_string` y funciones `mysql_*` (que están deprecadas) sería pasarse a `mysqli_*` o `PDO` y consultas preparadas/parametrizadas

Comment: Hola Amigo Me Ayudas Por favor?
Me Lanza este ERROR 
[object HTMLParagraphElement]
Cuandor deveria trasladar el valor Numerico.


El Codigo Utilizado es el Siguiente:
`<h3 class="about">GAME OVER</h3>
<p class="your">tus puntos:</p> 
<span class=current-score>0</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/score.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
         "score": $("#current-score").text()
    }
});
 pero al convertirlo a un objeto $("#current-score") no se transfiere.
</script>`
Cualquier Pista , O Ayuda me sera de mucha Utilidad , Gracias

Comment: @BryanBWeiss si estas usando `class` entonces debería ser `$(".current-score").text()`. En el ejemplo de tu pregunta estabas usando `id`

Comment: @CésarBustíos ESTOY MUY CERCA DE LOGRARLO  al utilizar `(.current-score)`  el valor por defaul es 0 y eso guarda sql update,  solo necesito encontrar una forma guardar el valor de la variable  algo así como `(.score + valor) ` Alguna idea Amigo :)

Comment: @BryanBWeiss de donde sale `valor`? No lo veo en tu código, no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer en tu último comentario. Si es necesario puedes editar tu pregunta y poner mas detalles

Comment: @BryanBWeiss mira mi última actualización de la respuesta

Comment: Ups ya lo habia editado no me permitía,   y pues `valor` seria la suma del punto actual ya que por si solo (.Score.) no me quiere guardar el puntaje :/ solo `span class` lo muestra no se que estoy asiendo mal pero estoy enloquesiendo :/ no se porque no hace el UPDATE a tiempo real sino que permanece en 0

Comment: @CésarBustíos Lo Logramos!!!
La clave era incluirlo en el ARCHIVO JS dentro de la Function y no en el HTML  TE LO AGRADEZCO César Bustíos Sos Un Maestro!!! mis puntos están en la BD :)

<br/>

`function gameScore(){

$('#ribbon').addClass('hide');

var highScore=localStorage.getItem("high-score");

var score=(snakeLength-startLength)*10;

$('.current-score').html(score);

request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/score.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {

        "score":parseInt ($(".current-score").text())
    }
});
`

Comment: @BryanBWeiss muy bien! Te felicito, finalmente tu mismo encontraste el problema ;)

Answer (score 0):

Muy buena tu respuesta estaba haciendo algo similar y me ayudo muchísimo.

Aqui te dejo mi código

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">                          
    //Metodo para cargar el formulario **************** AQUI USO ALGO DIFERENTE PARA PODER LEER EL id DEL DIV ******
    $("body").on('submit', '#formOrder', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if ($('#formOrder').valid()) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "imagesOrderProcesar.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
        "Order": $("#output").text()
    },
        success: function(respuesta) {
                    if (respuesta.error == 1) {
                        $('#error1').show();
                        setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#error1').hide();
                        }, 1000);
                        window.location.href='login.php'; 
                    }

                    if (respuesta.exito == 1) {
                        document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';                       
                    }                       
                }
            });
        }
    }); 

    function Salir() {
        window.location.href="propertylist.php";
    }    
</script>
```