# Pasar variable JavaScript a PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Mediante un `combobox`(cargado por nombres de una base de datos mediante un `while` hice una función de `javascript` que cuando yo escoja un nombre del `combobox` me traiga en un input aparte la cédula de ese nombre.

He leído sobre `js` y me quedó claro que `js` solo está de parte del cliente, como tal no puede interactuar de parte del servidor.

¿Podrían colaborar con los pasos de convertir una variable `js` a `php` para insertarla a una base de datos?

Comment: http://jhosuepardo.com/diseno-web/como-pasar-variables-de-javascript-a-php-y-viceversa/

Comment: @Rastalovely, por qué no lo dejas como una respuesta elaborada y así la puedo votar?

Comment: @lois6b No creo que sea necesario

Comment: @Rastalovely Si lo es. Quiero decir, tu quieres ayudarle y este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Los comentarios son para aclarar cosas.

Comment: @lois6b hee agregado una respuesta que considero mas apropiada

Comment: @Rastalovely en comentarios, él mismo dice que no guarda las variables, es solo para mostrar en pantalla. Ya tengo esa parte, yo selecciono el nombre en el combo box y cuando la selecciono, a lado tengo un input disabled que es donde me muestra la cédula de ese nombre. Pero como lo que se muestra en el input es neto js no puedo guardar esa cedula en base de datos.

Comment: He agregado esa parte espero te sirva. Saludos @Santiago

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Pasar El texto del Contenedor <span id> a una Variable PHP](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2589/pasar-el-texto-del-contenedor-span-id-a-una-variable-php)

Answer (score 6):

Este es tu Combobox, el cual como lo mencionas no tienes problema en el llenado

> Mi.html

```
<select data-no-selected="Sin Seleccionar"  id="tuid"  name="tuid"  required class="form-control></select>
```

En un archivo JS, en esta parte cuando el archivo cargue, se ejecutara lo que coloques en tu Load, ejemplo:

> Aqui puedes hacer el llenado de tu Combobox
>
> Mi.JS

```
$("#micombo").load("llenarcombo.php");
```

¿Pero que contiene llenarcombo.php?

```
 $orden=mysqli_query($cn,"select * from tutabla");
 echo '<option value="">Seleccione el Registro</option>';
 while($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($orden))
 {
    echo '<option value="'.$datos['id'].'">'.$datos['nombre'].' </option>';
 }
```

> Como lo mencionas cuando cambies la selección de tu combo, se debe enviar la variable esto es gracias a travez del evento "Change", esta variable la recoges  en tu php

```
$("document").ready(function()
{
 $("#tuid").change(function(){
  var id2=$("#tuid").val();
  $.get("tuphp.php",{parametro:id2})
  .done(function(data){
  $("#mostraren").html(data);
  })
 })
}
```

¿Pero que contiene tu php.php?

```
$param=$_GET["parametro"];
include('conexion.php');
$orden=mysqli_query($cn,"select * from tabla2 where id=$param");
echo '<option value="">Seleccione Cedula</option>';
while($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($orden))
{
    echo '<option value="'.$datos['id'].'">'.$datos['nombre'].'</option>';
}
```

Y Para insertar Datos?

En esta parte recibes los parámetros que enviaste a travez de JS

```
 $param=$_GET["parametro"];
 $param1=$_GET["parametro1"];
 $orden=mysqli_query($cn,"INSERT INTO tabla2 (dato1,dato2) values param=$param1 where id=$param");
 echo "Datos Insertado";
```

Answer (score 3):

Esta sería la parte de Javascript, en donde a la función le asignamos el valor a la variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var variable ="Hola esta es mi variable";

    function onEnviar(){
       document.getElementById("variable").value=variable;
    }
</script>
```

Y este el formulario donde vamos a darle el valor a la "variable", cuando se de clic en el botón se invoca al método **onsubmit** que llamará a nuestra función **JavaScript**

```
<form action="ejemploVariable.php" id="formulario" method="post" name="formulario" onsubmit="onAceptar()">
    <input id="variable" name="variable" type="hidden" />
    <input id="aceptar" type="submit" value="Aceptar" />
</form>
```

ejemploVariable.php

Leemos los parámetros que se pasaron por POST, en este caso "variable"

```
<?php
    echo "Resultado variable: ".$_POST['variable'];
?>
```

Y con esto nos saldría en la pantalla lo siguiente:

**Resultado variable: Hola esta es mi variable**

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo podrías realizar mediante `ajax`. Como veo que estás usando `JQuery`, podrías hacerlo fácilmente de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: tuUrl,
    data: {tuVariable: 'tuVariable'},
    success: exitoso
})
```

De esta manera, podrás llamar al fichero PHP que necesites utilizar mediante el atributo `url`.

Con el atributo `data` puedes enviar la variable de `Javascript` que tengas que utilizar en tu PHP y con el atributo `success` estarás llamando a la función `exitoso` cuando hayas realizado tus funciones de PHP, es decir, cuando la función de ajax haya sido completada.

En PHP simplemente podrías recuperar los datos mediante `$_POST['tuVariable']`.

Comment: Creo que nuestro compañero va empezando con la parte de Jquery y mandarlo a Ajax seria un poco apresurado

Comment: @Rastalovely Sí, puede ser pero me parecía una idea interesante comentársela.

Comment: Me parece correcto darle el camino mas valido @Error404  es ajax una de las mejores formas!

Answer (score 0):

Correcto! `jquery` es un framework que trabaja del lado del cliente, pero SI puede interactuar con datos del servidor, hay diferentes formas de poder obtener y enviar datos a un archivo `php`. Una de las mas ocupadas es `ajax` que te ayuda a hacer tareas asíncronas (en segundo plano).

Me imagino que tu archivo donde tienes tus datos le envias un arreglo o consultas a la base de datos supongamos que tienes una variable llamada `$datos`, esta variable contiene un arreglo con nombres y sus respectivas cedulas. Para trabajar con jquery esos datos puedes hacer :

```
var datos = '<?php echo json_encode($datos); ?>';
```

Con este codigo obtendras un arreglo `json` de tus datos luego puedes jugar con

```
//es la variable anterior guardado
var nombres = JSON.parse(datos);
```

Y aqui ya puedes ir recorriendo tus datos como un arreglo de jquery. Lo demas es anexar los datos con ids