# Pasar una variable javascript a php sin input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, php5

Hola a todos por favor si alguien me puede ayudar necesito pasar una variable javascript a php.. tengo esta funcion

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function operacion(field) {
     var form = field.parentNode; 
     var numero1 = form.cantidad.value;         
     var numero2 = form.precio.value;         
     form.total.value = ( numero1 * numero2 ); 
      }    
    </script>
```

y me imprime el resultado en el input total

```
   <td><label>Total</label></td>
   <td><input align="right" type="text" name="total"></td>
```

lo que quiero es que esa variable total de javascript me imprima algo asi

```
 <?php
  echo $total = aqui quiero que aparezca la variable total del javascript sin el input;
  ?>
```

Si alquien me puede ayudar le agradezco mucho de ante mano...

Comment: Hay varios ejemplos de esta pregunta, como [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2589/pasar-el-texto-del-contenedor-span-id-a-una-variable-php). También puedes utilizar el buscador para encontrar algo similar a [pasar variable js a php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=pasar%20variable%20javascript%20a%20php).

Comment: la verdad no entiendo como resolver mi problema :/

Comment: Utilizando *ajax* puedes comunicar el javascript con html, como el de [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: No se como hacerlo puedes ayudarme por favor

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) de jQuery, por ejemplo:

#### Javascript `script.js`

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'ejemplo.php',
  // estas son las variables que querés pasar a PHP
  // donde el "key" es el nombre que va a recibir
  // en el archivo php como $_POST['total']
  data: {total: 1239.32},
  // esta función se llama cuando termina de procesar el
  // request y utiliza el response para obtener la data
  // que se imprimió desde PHP
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

#### PHP `ejemplo.php`

```
$total = $_POST['total'];

// ejecuto lo que necesite hacer con la variable
// por ejemplo: le agrego el signo $
$total = "$" + $total;

// esta es una forma de devolverle el nuevo valor a
// javascript y lo va a agarrar el "success" del ajax
echo json_encode($total);
```

#### html

```
<!-- importo el jQuery para poder utilizar ajax -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- importo el script donde se va a ejecutar -->
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: gracias si por el ejemplo.. :( hice algo parecido